# Term simplification in single atomic orbital (LCAO) model

Tags: solid-state-physics, tight-binding

I was following the text of one of our lectures where we derived for a single-orbial $\phi(\vec{r})$ LCAO model for the band-structure of a crystal:

$$E_{\vec{k}} = E_a + \frac{\sum_{\vec{R}}e^{i\vec{k}\vec{R}}h(\vec{R})}{1+\sum_{\vec{R}\ne 0}e^{i\vec{k}\vec{R}}I(\vec{R})}$$

with
$$I(\vec{R}) = \int\textrm{d}^3r~\phi^*(\vec{r}) \phi(\vec{r}-\vec{R})$$
$$h(\vec{R}) = \int\textrm{d}^3r~\phi^*(\vec{r}) \Delta U(\vec{r}, \vec{R})\phi(\vec{r}-\vec{R})$$

and then made a nearest neighbor approximation, yielding
$$E_{\vec{k}} = E_a + \frac{h(0) + \sum_{\vec{R}\in\{n.n.\}}e^{i\vec{k}\vec{R}}h(\vec{R})}{1+\sum_{\vec{R}\in\{n.n.\}}e^{i\vec{k}\vec{R}}I(\vec{R})}$$
up to which point everything is clear to me.

The text then (stating $h(\vec{R})$ and $I(\vec{R})$ are small and "we can thus expand with respect to them") further approximated

$$E_{\vec{k}} = E_a + h(0) + \sum_{\vec{R}\in\{n.n.\}}\left[ h(\vec{R}) - h(0)I(\vec{R}) \right]e^{i\vec{k}\vec{R}}$$

Unfortunately, I don't understand the last step. How can the last simplification be derived by "expanding with respect to  $h(\vec{R})$ and $I(\vec{R})$"?